# Angular 4 Form Validators - minLength & maxLength does not work on field type number

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, angular4-forms

I am trying to develop a contact form, I want user to enter phone number values between length 10-12.

Notably same validation is working on **Message** field, Its only **number** field which is giving me trouble.

[I found this answer but it is of no use for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064592/angular-2-form-validation-minlength-validator-is-not-working)

I have code like following :

HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="myFormSubmit()">
      <input type="number" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
      <input type="text" formControlName="message" placeholder="Message">
       <button class="button" type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

TS :

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     phone: ['',  [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(12)]],
     message: ['',  [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(100)]]
});`
```

Comment: Numbers don't have *length* as far as form validation is concerned. If you want 10-12 digits, what you really want is numbers between 1,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,000,000, surely?

Comment: Yes, I need numbers between 10000000000 to 999999999999

Comment: Then use that, rather than trying to check the length.

Comment: So there is no default method for that? we'll have to create one to limit those?

Comment: What makes you say that? See https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators, which shows both `min` and `max`.

Comment: Thanks, My mistake, Just saw it, wrote it, and it worked. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Used it like following and worked perfectly :

```js
phone: ['',  [Validators.required, Validators.min(10000000000), Validators.max(999999999999)]],
```

customValidationService :

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class customValidationService {
   static checkLimit(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (c.value && (isNaN(c.value) || c.value < min || c.value > max)) {
            return { 'range': true };
        }
        return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I know I'm a year late here, and it's not exactly what was asked in the OP, but *nobody* will want to enter a phone number as `<input type='number'>`. The answer under "Update 1" is correct for integers, but *a phone number is not an integer*.  [This](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md) isn't even the "falsehoods about phone numbers" piece I was looking for, but it has a lot of good points.

Comment: But with this soution you can add zeros on the left withour being controlled , maxlength(10) and max(999999999) are not the same -_-

Answer (score 18):

try this working sample code :

**component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" 
    (ngFormSubmit)="registerUser(myForm.value)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!myForm.controls['phone'].valid}">
            <label for="phone">Email</label>
            <input type="phone" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" 
            class="form-control">
            <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="myForm.controls['phone'].hasError('minlength')">
                Your phone must be at least 5 characters long.
            </p>
            <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="myForm.controls['phone'].hasError('maxlength')">
                Your phone cannot exceed 10 characters.
            </p>
            <p class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="myForm.controls['phone'].hasError('required') && myForm.controls['phone'].dirty">
                phone is required
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: any;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            phone: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10)])]
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I have a trick that 100% work.

Define input of type 'text' and not 'number'.

For eg:

```
<input placeholder="OTP" formControlName="OtpUserInput" type="text">
```

Then use pattern which is part of Validation.

Like :

```
this.ValidOtpForm = this.formbuilder.group({
             OtpUserInput: new FormControl(
              { value:'', disabled: false },
          [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(6),
          Validators.pattern('[0-9]')
        ]),
});
```

It means we define input type text that is suitable for min length and we also
define pattern(validation) for numeric value so that we can achieve both
validation.

Remaining code :

```
<mat-error *ngIf="RegistrationForm.controls['Password'].hasError('minlength')">Use 6 or more characters with a mix of letters</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="ValidOtpForm.controls['OtpUserInput'].hasError('pattern')">Please enter numeric value.</mat-error>
```

Comment: Excellent worked perfect for me. A small detail is that when we declare `minlength` in the `mat-error` note that it is lowercase, while in the validator it is `minLength` with uppercase.

Answer (score 8):

You should not use length here, for min and max use custom validator like this,

```
var numberControl = new FormControl("", CustomValidators.number({min: 10000000000, max: 999999999999 }))
```

**[`Angular2 min/max validators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators)**

Answer (score 5):

This trick will be helpful

In **.html** file

```
 <input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
```

In **.ts** file

The below code restrict string characters

```
    public onKeyUp(event: any) {
    const NUMBER_REGEXP = /^\s*(\-|\+)?(\d+|(\d*(\.\d*)))([eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*$/;
    let newValue = event.target.value;
    let regExp = new RegExp(NUMBER_REGEXP);

    if (!regExp.test(newValue)) {
      event.target.value = newValue.slice(0, -1);
    }
   }
```

and other validation

```
phone: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required, 
         Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{0,30}$')])
      ])],
```

The above pattern code allow number upto 30 digits.
If you want minimum two digits, you can do like this

```
 Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{2,30}$')
```

Comment: Why use extra event `keyup` when Angular can do it without it?

Comment: I  added `keyup` event to remove  special characters or operators while entering otherwise its up to you to add `keyup` event or not

Comment: Using `type="number"` removes special characters, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it removes special characters in `type= number` but it will have `+` , `-` , `e` while entering . If you want to restrict these operators while entering use `keyup` event else everything is fine.

Comment: I only had to use other validation section.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **pattern** instead to validate your phone number, and change your input type to text

```
<input type="text" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
```

and use this pattern for phone number tha have a length between 10 and 12

```
phonePattern = /^[0-9]{10,12}$/;
```

and change the validator on your form control

```
phone: ['',  [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.phonePattern)]],
```

and you can display the error:

```
<div *ngIf="myForm.get('phone').invalid">
      <div class="error-message invalid-feedback" *ngIf="myForm.get('phone').hasError('required')">
        required!
      </div>
      <div class="error-message invalid-feedback" *ngIf="myForm.get('phone').hasError('pattern')">
        invalid!
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Form Validation of multiple parameters or multiple conditions should be composed as single validator otherwise you will get observable or promise error:

```
phone: ['',  Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.min(10000000000), Validators.max(999999999999)])],
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `number` field, you can validate min and max *values* using built in Angular validation, like this:

**.ts**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

private myNumberFieldMin: number = 1;
private myNumberFieldMax: number = 1000000;

constructor() {
      this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        myNumberField
      })

this.myForm.controls.myNumberField.setValidators([
  Validators.min(this.myNumberFieldMin),
  Validators.max(this.myNumberFieldMax)
]);
```

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="number" formControlName="myNumberField">

  <div *ngIf="this.myForm.controls['myNumberField'].errors && this.myForm.controls['myNumberField'].errors.min">
    <span class="error-message">Value must be at least {{myNumberFieldMin}}</span>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="this.myForm.controls['myNumberField'].errors && this.myForm.controls['myNumberField'].errors.max">
    <span class="error-message">Maximum value is {{myNumberFieldMax}}</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep `<input type="number" />` and just transform the int values to strings.

```
const phoneControl: FormControl = this.myForm.controls.phone;

// Do not forget to unsubscribe

phoneControl.valueChanges.subscribe(v => {

  // When erasing the input field, cannot read toString() of null, can occur
  phoneControl.setValue((v && v.toString()) || null, { emitEvent: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-error>
   <span *ngIf="phone.errors?.required">campo obrigatório</span>
   <span *ngIf="phone.errors?.minlength">o nº deve conter no mínimo 13 dígitos</span>
   <span *ngIf="phone.errors?.maxlength">o nº deve conter no máximo 13 dígitos</span>
</mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used `maxLength` instead of `maxlength` (notice the lowercase `l` ) in the template.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div nz-col [nzXs]="24" [nzSm]="12" nz-form-control nzHasFeedback>
                                <nz-input formControlName="password" [nzPlaceHolder]="'password'" [nzType]="'password'" [nzSize]="'large'" (ngModelChange)="validateConfirmPassword()">
                                </nz-input>
                                <div nz-form-explain *ngIf="getFormControl('password').dirty&&getFormControl('password').hasError('minlength')">Your password must be at least 5 characters long. </div>
                                <div nz-form-explain *ngIf="getFormControl('password').dirty&&getFormControl('password').hasError('maxlength')">Your password cannot exceed 15 characters. </div>
                                <div nz-form-explain *ngIf="getFormControl('password').dirty&&getFormControl('password').hasError('required')">Please input your password!</div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Ts File
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'ftl-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class PasswordChecker implements OnInit {
     validateForm: FormGroup;
     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
      password: ['', [Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(15)]],
    });
}

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of adding comments to your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to validate a field by multiple validators then, You should try this

```
phone: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required, 
        Validators.minLength(10),
        Validators.maxLength(12)])
      ])],
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [Compose()](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) method, compose multiple validators into a single function.

Update .TS file as below,

`this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     phone: ['',  Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(12)])],
     message: ['',  Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(100)])]
});`