# how to enter only 3 digit number in valid form?

Tags: javascript, angular

can you please tell me how to validate form when user enter only 3 digit number (not alpha) then it is valid form else invalid .I tried using `maxength` and `minlength` but not working .here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cttwtq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
      cardname: ['', [Validators.required , Validators.minLength(3),Validators.minLength(3)]],

    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Form Validators - minLength & maxLength does not work on field type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129719/angular-4-form-validators-minlength-maxlength-does-not-work-on-field-type-nu)

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeric-formatter.. it will prevent user from entering digits more than the length

Answer (score 2):

You set the input to type number, So min and max length won't work. you have to change it to text and just add a pattern validation, something like:

```
this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
 cardname: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), 
 Validators.maxLength(3), Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')])],
});
```

I forked your example, you can check it out:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwfsbq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: As a suggestion, you could remove `Validators.minLength(3)` and `Validators.maxLength(3)`, then change the pattern to '^[0-9]{3}$'

Comment: @ChrisForrence, you can do alot of things, of course, sometimes you want some more distinguish of the errors, without custom valid it. and its not my problem so I have no idea what he try to achieve at the end. so I've just fixed his problem and from here he can continue to improve. thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use Validator.min and Validator.max

```
cardname: ['', [Validators.required , Validators.min(100),Validators.max(999)]]
```

Comment: Great! But how do we validate numbers like 056?

Comment: Just as a heads up, if the number leads off with a 0, this won't quite do the trick (e.g. "007")

Comment: if you want validate 0XX, as string, the only way is using a regexp, but you lost the advantage of the native restriction of only let that the user input numbers, if you want a number, 7 is the same that 007 and you can use min(0).