# Error message not showing in a reactive form

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular11, error-messaging

I have a reactive form with three error messages, but when I type something on the textboxes no errors are appearing, I´ve searching for something missing or mistyped, but I can´t see anything. Any help will be appreciated.
Angular version: 12.2.10

Ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { ServicioSettings } from '../data/servicio-settings';
import { DataService } from '../data/data.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-verhoras',
  templateUrl: './verhoras.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./verhoras.component.css']
})
export class VerhorasComponent implements OnInit {

  servicioSettings: ServicioSettings = {
    IdTecnico: null,
    tecnico: null,
    servicioRealizado: null,
    fechaDeInicio: null,
    horaDeInicio: null,
    semanaDelAno: null,    
    fechaDeFinalizacion: null,
    horaDeFinalizacion: null,
    cantidadDeHoras: null,
    tipoDeHora: null
  };

  myForm: FormGroup;  
  items: ServicioSettings;
  submitted = false;

   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private dataService: DataService)  {   }       

    iniciarFormulario(){      
      this.myForm = new FormGroup({        
        IdTecnico: new FormControl(this.servicioSettings.IdTecnico, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30)]),        
        semanaDelAno: new FormControl(this.servicioSettings.semanaDelAno,[Validators.required])       
      });     
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.iniciarFormulario();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.myForm.valid) {
        console.log(this.myForm.value)
        this.dataService.getServicioSettingsForm(this.myForm.value).subscribe(
            //result => console.log('success ', result),
            result => this.items = result,
            error => console.log('error ', error)
        );
    }

  }
}
```

Html file:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="IdTecnico">Id técnico (*)</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="IdTecnico" name="IdTecnico" formControlName="IdTecnico"/>
    <div class="alert-danger"
      *ngIf="
        myForm.get('IdTecnico').invalid &&
        (myForm.get('IdTecnico').dirty || myForm.get('IdTecnico').touched)
      "
    >
      <div *ngIf="myForm.get('IdTecnico').errors.required">
        El IdTecnico es requerido
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="myForm.get('IdTecnico').errors.minlength">
        El IdTecnico debe ser mínimo de 4 caracteres
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="myForm.get('IdTecnico').errors.maxlength">
        El IdTecnico debe ser máximo de 30 caracteres
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="semanaDelAno">Semana del año (*)</label>
    <input
      type="number"
      class="form-control"
      id="semanaDelAno"
      formControlName="semanaDelAno"
    />
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

The form is just a couple of textboxes and a button, the idea is that for example when typing only one character on the first one, an error of min length should appears.

Comment: Looks okay? Try {{ myForm.get('IdTecnico').errors | json }} somewhere in the template (outside the ngIf) and see what it shows?

Comment: Null comes out when pressing the button

Comment: Weird. Can you remove the default value in the FormControl?

Comment: Done... this is the form.value    {IdTecnico: 1, semanaDelAno: 1}
IdTecnico: 1
semanaDelAno: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object               null still appears

Comment: @JhonJairoHernandezPulgarin `minLength, maxLength` Does not works on `type=number` should be `type='text'` [check](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qeg65y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @JhonJairoHernandezPulgarin Check if this helps [Angular 4 Form Validators - minLength & maxLength does not work on field type number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129969/6099811)

Comment: @JhonJairoHernandezPulgarin  `min, max` Validators available for `input type number`

Comment: Ah damn - I completely missed that ;-)

Comment: Have you imported `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module of this component?

Answer (score 0):

Your required should work as it is set correctly. For `IdTecnico` input you set `type="number"`. To validate number type input you cannot use `minLength` or `maxLength`. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome) tread for additional info. If you do need numeric input you can try use `min` and `max` validators. However, looking at your input you better go with text input and add some custom validator checking if input is some numeric value.

Did not saw @JhonJairoHernandezPulgarin comment - you can upvote it as it is correct.