# Reactive form validations always valid - Angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create some simple reactive validation for at project, but it keeps returning it as "Valid" even though it shouldn't be.
I'm trying to validate the length of a number, which must be between 7-16 digits.

**card-add-c.component.html**

```html
    <h1>Add credit card</h1>
    
    <form [formGroup]="addCardForm"> <!-- (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">-->
    
      <div class="cross-validation" [class.cross-validation-error]="addCardForm.errors?.identityRevealed && addCardForm.touched">
        <label for="card_number">Card number</label>
        <input type="number" id="card_number" class="form-control" formControlName="card_number" required>
        <label *ngIf="card_number.invalid && card_number.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="card_number.errors?.minLength">
            Name must be at least 7 characters long.
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="card_number.errors?.maxlength">
            Name must be 16 or less characters long.
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button" type="submit" [disabled]="!addCardForm.valid">Add card</button>
      <p>Form Status: {{ addCardForm.status }}</p>
    </form>
```

**card-add-c.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { cardService } from '../credit-card.service';
    import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-card-add-c',
      templateUrl: './card-add-c.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./card-add-c.component.css']
    })
    export class CardAddCComponent implements OnInit {
    
     
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      addCardForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        card_number: new FormControl('',  [Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(16)]),
        // more here, but currently commented out, as I'm working on only card_number
      })
    
      constructor(
        private cardService: cardService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        ) { }
    
    
      card = this.cardService.addCard(this.addCardForm.value);
    
    
      onSubmit():void{
    
    
        this.cardService.addCard(this.addCardForm.value).subscribe(res =>{
          
          console.log("Card " + this.addCardForm.value + " added!");
        })
    
        
        console.log("Card added");
      }
    
      get card_number() {
        return this.addCardForm.get('card_number')!;
      }
    
    }
```

I've looked at a lot of documentation, and is *should* work, but it doesn't.
The requried statement works, but not the lengths.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

**Outputs:**

*Startup:*

[image: Initial load]

---

*Too few*

[image: Too few numbers]

---

*Too many*

[image: Too many numbers]

Comment: Can you try changing to type="text" for the input?

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46129719/2050306

Answer (score 1):

`minLength` and `maxLength` are for strings, but your input type is a `number`.

Given a credit card can start with `0`, you might want to change the input wit `text` and maybe check only numbers are there.